# question about sets of polynomials with a special agreement guarantee

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field and $S\subset\mathbb{F}_{\leq d}[x,y]$, a set of bivariate polynomials over $\mathbb{F}$ of degree at most $d\ll|\mathbb{F}|$.  Assume the linear span of $S$ is all of $\mathbb{F}_{\leq d}[x,y]$.  Let $L$ be the set of one-dimensional lines in $\mathbb{F}^2$.  Suppose the following property holds: for any $P(x,y)\in S$ and $\ell\in L$, there exists $Q(x,y)\in S$ st $P|_\ell=Q|_\ell$.  Can we lower bound $|S|$?  $|S|=|\mathbb{F}|^{\Omega(d)}$ would be ideal.  Is this even true?

Comment: If it's easier, I'd also be interested in a solution to the same problem one dimension up: $S\subset\mathbb{F}_{\leq d}[x,y,z]$ a set of trivariate polynomials, and $L$ the set of all two-dimensional affine subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^3$, guarantee is that for all $P\in S$ and $H\in L$, there exists $Q\in S$ st $P|_H=Q|_H$.

Comment: The set of all polynomials of degree at most 1 fits for every $d\geq 1$. Did you miss some condition? (If you need, you may multiply all of them by $x^{d-1}$...)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I'm not interested in $S$ contained in a low-dimension subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{\leq d}[x,y]$.  Question updated.

Comment: I did not get it. The condition is not trivially true by picking Q=P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still, a required estimate is hopeless. Set $q=|\mathbb F|$.

Take into $S$ all polynomials of the form $k(\ell x+my+n)^d$ with $k,\ell,m,n\in\mathbb F$ (there are in fact $\Omega(q^3)$ such polynomials). They satisfy all the requirements. Indeed, if $ux+vy+w=0$ is an equation of some affine line, then $k(\ell x+my+n)^d$ and $k(\ell x+my+n+ux+vy+w)^d$ are equal on this line. Moreover, these polynomials span all the polynomials of degree $\le d$ by Vandermonde.

Comment: OK yeah looks like it's not true in general.  Thanks.